# Pgfplots closes plot cycle when it should not

Tags: pgfplots, luatex

I experience a strange behaviour with `pgfplots`.

I plot a series of datasets with no problems, but suddenly when I plot my last set of data, a line is drawn from the last point back to the first point (or vice versa, I can't tell).

First I thought this is an issue with my dataset, but it is not. The x-axis starts at 600 and ends at 4500.

Because of the large number of datapoints, I plot with `LuaLaTex`, but I do not think that this has anything to do with it.

Data is read from a table with whitespace separated columns and as I mentioned three ut of four datasets plot perfectly fine.

Has anyone seen a behaviour like this before? What might trigger pgfplots to think it needs to close the cycle?

```
Wavenumber S3-274C S57-470C S61-530C S78-Waven S78-600C
599.79222 0.00111376889640803 -0.00318693372816191 0.000493685423608535 600.03332 0.00245899230729994
600.03332 0.000685106575644899 -0.00300781635600173 -0.00075611249618284 600.51551 0.00355253129408962
600.27441 0.00020054240413265 -0.00292040072006049 -0.00387528077430245 600.99771 0.00322643347723173
.
.
.
4499.0656 -0.000192050912304183 -0.000206136040667906 0.000470869306110851 4498.5834 -7.20299845689941e-06
4499.3067 -0.000229780242038388 -0.000840102422491839 0.000772319837166174 4499.0656 -0.000583129304457668
4499.5478 0.000222526133933754 -0.000688254151215666 0.000522590786071012 4499.5478 -0.000741882168643009
```

---

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.9\textwidth,
ymin=-0.01,
ymax=0.02,
line width=0.3pt]
\addplot[orange,mark=none%,y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+0.09}}
] table[x=S78-Waven, y=S78-600C] {MBTC-only.dat};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2012/08/29 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.100)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/11/07 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.25)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2012/03/30 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.38)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2012/08/27 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.22)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
pgfplots.sty    2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29)
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

**UPDATE:**

I took the data of the strange dataset and saved it unchanged in another file. Now it works with no problem. Must be some kind of error in the reading of the table or maybe my slightly complicated column naming scheme.